# Add dependency only for combination of two specific build flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have two flavor dimensions in my project - 'app' (full, demo) and 'market' (google, amazon, etc.) and I want to use login-with-amazon-sdk.jar library only in one build combination: full-amazon.

I've placed login-with-amazon-sdk.jar into src/fullAmazon/libs folder. Is it possible to include it only into 'full-amazon' build variant?

Comment: Well, with what you have, you should be in OK shape, assuming that you are loading in JARs in your dependencies. Push come to shove, use `fullAmazonCompile` to point it to this particular JAR for this particular build variant. What are your specific symptoms/problems at this point?

Comment: If I try to use fullAmazonCompile then gradle gives error Gradle DSL method not found: 'fullAmazonCompile()'
Gradle does not understand compile command with two flavors.

Comment: Hmmmm... perhaps they don't have flavor dimensions working with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use flavor dimensions. Use build variants and product flavors instead. For example you have the 2 product flavors google + amazon and 2 build variants full + demo. 
Then you can combine the folder names like this:
googleFull
googleDemo
amazonFull
amazonDemo

Was this helpful for you? lmk